# Select only matching files using multiple patterns in list.files

Tags: r, regex, string, list

I have the following csv files and I only want to select the ones which have matching 'pop' and 'throughput' values in each string:

```
example_pop_high_throughput_high_strategy.csv
example_pop_high_throughput_base_strategy.csv
example_pop_high_throughput_low_strategy.csv
example_pop_base_throughput_high_strategy.csv
example_pop_base_throughput_base_strategy.csv
example_pop_base_throughput_low_strategy.csv
example_pop_low_throughput_high_strategy.csv
example_pop_low_throughput_base_strategy.csv
example_pop_low_throughput_low_strategy.csv
```

I want only these:

```
example_pop_high_throughput_high_strategy.csv                
example_pop_base_throughput_base_strategy.csv
example_pop_low_throughput_low_strategy.csv
```

I can use list.files to select all files with, for example, 'high':

```
file_names <- list.files("made/up/path", pattern = c("high"))
```

Although, trying to do this twice to just match 'high' and 'high', didn't work:

```
file_names <- list.files("made/up/path", pattern = c("high", "high"))
```

Is there a way to select the files with matching 'pop' and 'throughput' values, preferably in a single expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should work:

```
file_names <- list.files("made/up/path", pattern = c("(low|base|high).+\\1"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
^.*?pop_([^_]+)_throughput_\1.*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xs8lgp/1)